# SQL INSERT IGNORE: skip values in a special case

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm trying to skip an `INSERT` in a particular case, where one of two involved values is a specific value:

```
// this can work if Beech allready exists
INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table (col_wood_name, col_type)
VALUES ("Beech", 0)

// this should be skipped if Beech allready exists with col_type = 1
INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table (col_wood_name, col_type)
VALUES ("Beech", 1)

my_table:
id      col_wood_name     col_type       other_column_1     other_column_2     etc_cols
1       Beech             0              ...                ...                ...
2       Fir               0              ...                ...                ...
3       Beech             1              ...                ...                ...
4       Pine              1              ...                ...                ...
5       Beech             1 // here is my problem, how can I avoid to insert a tree if col_type == 1?
6       Beech             0 // it's ok because col_type == 0
```

how can I avoid to insert a tree name if `col_type` == 1?

I know I can create unique key on `col_wood_name` and `col_type` using something like:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD UNIQUE(col_wood_name, col_type);
```

but this is incomplete because this should work only if `col_type` is `1`, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way of doing that in one query. Use Stored Procedures or an additional query in your application.

Answer (score 0):

How many different col_type are possible?

I ask because of design reasons.  If you only have two columns in the table, I'm not seeing how it would be beneficial not to do the unique constraint on the two fields.

Comment: the table has other columns, and id, user_creator and more, I've wrote only the columns where I've found the problem, sorry for my unclear question.

Comment: No need to apologize.  I just figure that a better table set up is needed.  I was thinking about a two table set up, one with the tree and the type, and then another table with individual records from the ids of that table, but that still wouldn't prevent you from having multipl Beech/1 records.